# How to get the route by helper name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following set of routes which point to the same view:

```
get 'mypath', to: 'home#mypath', as: 'mypath'
get 'mypath-v2', to: 'home#mypath', as: 'mypath_v2'
get 'mypath-v3', to: 'home#mypath', as: 'mypath_v3'
```

How can I check if I am using one route or the other inside the view?

For example if I want to get `mypath-v2` or `mypath_v2`, how would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would call it by appending `_path` or `_url`

For instance here is an example in a link:

```
<%= link_to 'Link to mypath-v2 page', mypath_v2_path %>
```

OR

```
<%= link_to 'Link to mypath-v2 page', mypath_v2_url %>
```

To compare them you can look at the request object. When you call `request.path` or `request.fullpath` it will bring in the actual address request path of the link.

So...

```
<%= if request.path.eql?('mypath-v2') ? "Used It" : "Other Route" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, as for me it is better to do such things using params. You can define your routes like this:

```
get "mypath/:version", :as => "mypath"
```

In this case you will be able to use params[:version] to clarify current path.